# Laravel 5.3 : Auto Incrementing Unsigned TINYINT

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5.3, database-migration

I have a few tables where I need `tinyint` fields which have to be `unsigned` and set to `auto_increment`.

The [L5.3 Database : Migrations documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations) **does not** have a method to define `unsigned auto-incrementing tinyint`.

I have tried to implement it using the `DB::update()`. My migration file for the table looks like:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('table_name', function (Blueprint $table) 
    {
        $table->unsignedTinyInteger('field1');
        $table->string('field2', 255);
        $table->primary('field1');
        $table->index('field2');

        $field = "field1";
    });

    $this->addAutoIncrements($field);    

}

public function addAutoIncrements($field)
{
    DB::update('ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY $field TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT');
}
```

When I try `php artisan migrate` with such a migration file, it migrates *without* any errors but **is not assigning** `auto-increment`.

How do I resolved this? Should I do the update as a complete new migration? Has anyone done it before?

Comment: `$table->unsignedTinyInteger('field1')->increments();`

Comment: @Ali : That was what I tried first. Didn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second parameter for the `unsignedTinyInteger()` method is a boolean to flag if it is an autoincrementing field. It defaults to `false`, so you just need to update your migration to pass in `true`.

```
$table->unsignedTinyInteger('field1', true);
```

As a future note, the `tinyIncrements()` convenience method was added in Laravel 5.4.16 to do exactly that.

Comment: Had to take the `$table->primary('field1')` as the `unsignedTinyInteger('field1', true)` takes care of it.